# Characters not showing up in XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to edit an XML file that's being called from a Flash file, and I noticed that certain letters aren't showing up, like the letters "q" and "j." Here is the script from the Flash file:

```
var max_news_items = 5;
GetTitleText = function (news_xml, entry_index)
{
    var _loc2 = news_xml.firstChild.childNodes;
    var _loc1 = _loc2[entry_index].firstChild;
    return (_loc1.firstChild.nodeValue);
};
GetBodyText = function (news_xml, entry_index)
{
    var _loc2 = news_xml.firstChild.childNodes;
    var _loc1 = _loc2[entry_index].firstChild.nextSibling;
    return (_loc1.firstChild.nodeValue);
};
GetEntry = function (news_xml, index)
{
    var _loc1 = news_xml.firstChild.childNodes;
    return (_loc1[index]);
};
GetNewsCount = function (news_xml)
{
    var _loc1 = news_xml.firstChild.childNodes;
    return (_loc1.length);
};
ShowNews = function (news_xml)
{
    if (!news_xml.firstChild.hasChildNodes())
    {
        content_txt.text = "No info. available.";
        return (0);
    } // end if
    var _loc5 = news_xml.firstChild.childNodes;
    content_txt.text = "";
    for (var _loc1 = 0; _loc1 < _loc5.length; ++_loc1)
    {
        var _loc3 = GetTitleText(news_xml, _loc1);
        var _loc2 = GetBodyText(news_xml, _loc1);
        content_txt.htmlText = content_txt.htmlText + ("<u><b>" + _loc3 + "</b><br></u>");
        content_txt.htmlText = content_txt.htmlText + (_loc2 + "<br><br>");
    } // end of for
};
AddNewsEntry = function (news_xml, title, body)
{
    var _loc2 = news_xml.createElement("entry");
    if (title == "")
    {
        title = "";
    } // end if
    var _loc4 = news_xml.createElement("title");
    var _loc7 = news_xml.createTextNode(title);
    _loc4.appendChild(_loc7);
    _loc2.appendChild(_loc4);
    if (body == "")
    {
        body = "(none)";
    } // end if
    var _loc3 = news_xml.createElement("body");
    var _loc6 = news_xml.createTextNode(body);
    _loc3.appendChild(_loc6);
    _loc2.appendChild(_loc3);
    if (news_xml.firstChild.hasChildNodes())
    {
        news_xml.firstChild.insertBefore(_loc2, news_xml.firstChild.firstChild);
    }
    else
    {
        news_xml.firstChild.appendChild(_loc2);
    } // end else if
    while (GetNewsCount(news_xml) > max_news_items)
    {
        news_xml.firstChild.lastChild.removeNode();
    } // end while
};
EditNewsEntry = function (news_xml, node_index, title, body)
{
    var _loc1 = GetEntry(news_xml, node_index);
    if (title == "" && body == "")
    {
        _loc1.removeNode();
        return (0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (title == "")
        {
            title = "(none)";
        } // end if
        if (body == "")
        {
            body = "(none)";
        } // end if
    } // end else if
    _loc1.attributes.date = new Date().toString();
    var _loc4 = _loc1.firstChild.firstChild;
    var _loc5 = _loc1.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild;
    _loc4.nodeValue = title;
    _loc5.nodeValue = body;
};
SaveNews = function (news_xml)
{
    content_txt.htmlText = "<i>Saving and Loading...</i>";
    news_xml.xmlDecl = "";
    news_xml.sendAndLoad(save_script, news_xml);
};
RefreshNews = function (news_xml)
{
    content_txt.htmlText = "<i>Loading...</i>";
    news_xml.load(xml_file + "?" + new Date().getTime());
};
var xml_file = "text_store/leasing.xml";
var save_script = "leasing_save.php";
var news_xml = new XML();
news_xml.ignoreWhite = true;
news_xml.contentType = "text/xml";
news_xml.onLoad = function (success)
{
    if (success)
    {
        ShowNews(this);
    }
    else
    {
        content_txt.text = "Error loading Info.";
    } // end else if
};
RefreshNews(news_xml);
```

I'll be honest, I know barely anything about Flash and ActionScript, so I don't know where to begin to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely do not have all the required characters of your font embedded in the text field in which you are displaying the text.

In Flash you can select the text field, press the Embed button in the Properties panel and then set the range of characters that you need embedded.

It's better to limit the embedded characters to the smallest set needed, as the additional glyphs will increase the size of your SWF.